# An error occurred during execution; please try again later.Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have installed zend skeleton application framework.after Install running the browser its working good.
showing following page :

[image]

after insert module.run the code it also working good.

[image]

After created following to create Registerform.
src/Users/Form/RegisterForm.php

```
<?php
// filename : module/Users/src/Users/Form/RegisterForm.php
namespace Users\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;
class RegisterForm extends Form
{
public function __construct($name = null)
{
parent::__construct('Register');
$this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
$this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/formdata');
$this->add(array(
'name' => 'name',
'attributes' => array(
'type' => 'text',
),
'options' => array(
'label' => 'Full Name',
),
));
$this->add(array(
'name' => 'email',
'attributes' => array(
'type' => 'email',
),
'options' => array(
'label' => 'Email',
),
'attributes' => array(
'required' => 'required'
),
'filters' => array(
array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
),
'validators' => array(
array(
'name' => 'EmailAddress',
'options' => array(
'messages' => array(
\Zend\Validator\
EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => 'Email address format is
invalid'
)
)
)
)
));
}
}
```

The view for registration page is created in 
src/view/users/register/index.phtml

```
<section class="register">
<h2>Register</h2>
<?php if ($this->error): ?>
<p class="error">
There were one or more issues with your submission.
Please correct them as
indicated below.
</p>
<?php endif ?>
<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL,
array('controller'=>'Register', 'action' => 'process')));
$form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>
<dl class="zend_form">
<dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('name')); ?></dt>
<dd><?php
echo $this->formElement($form->get('name'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('name'));
?></dd>
<dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('email')); ?></
dt>
<dd><?php
echo $this->formElement($form->get('email'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('email'));
?></dd>
<dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('password'));
?></dt>
<dd><?php
echo $this->formElement($form->get('password'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('password'));
?></dd>
<dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('confirm_
password')); ?></dt>
<dd><?php
echo $this->formElement($form->get('confirm_password'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('confirm_
password'));
?></dd>
<dd><?php
echo $this->formElement($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('submit'));
?></dd>
</dl>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag() ?>
</section>
```

The view for the confirmation page is pretty straightforward, the view is created in
 src/view/users/register/confirm.phtml.

```
<section class="register-confirm">
<h2>Register Sucessfull</h2>
<p> Thank you for your registration. </p>
</section>
```

src/Users/Controller/RegisterController.php file

```
<?php
namespace Users\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Users\Form\RegisterForm;
class RegisterController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function indexAction()
{
$form = new RegisterForm();
$viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form' =>
$form));
return $viewModel;
}
public function confirmAction()
{
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
return $viewModel;
}
}
```

config/module.config.php:

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Users\Controller\Index' => 'Users\Controller\IndexController',
            'Users\Controller\Register' =>'Users\Controller\RegisterController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'users' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    // Change this to something specific to your module
                    'route'    => '/users',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        // Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
                        // the controllers for your module are found
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Users\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    // This route is a sane default when developing a module;
                    // as you solidify the routes for your module, however,
                    // you may want to remove it and replace it with more
                    // specific routes.
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'ZendSkeletonModule' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Finally i want expect output look like but i am getting error :
   [image]

but i am getting error:
 An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
 Additional information:
 Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException

```
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(233): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(198): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(103): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Array)
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(352): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(327): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\public\index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

please help me!!!

Comment: Please help me..if anybody have any idea please let me inform

Comment: same issues...if u solve u r issues.please post here

Comment: What is the rest of the error?

Comment: @chizzle update my rest of error

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered same problem making this example by the book.
Anyway, problem is that you are calling "view" located in

```
"src/view/users/register/index.phtml"
```

and in config/module.config.php you have set

```
    'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'ZendSkeletonModule' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

It should point to right file location **DIR** . **'/../src/view'**.
Or you should move this folder to right location **"module/Users/view"** (without "src") where all views should be.

Comment: please format it little bit. Put 4 spaces before code to distinguish

Answer (score 0):

I never used ZfcUser module witch I think it is...

Try the following:

```
//In RegisterForm.php remove this 2 lines

$this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
$this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/formdata');

//In your index.phtml change like this

$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('yourRouteName', array('action' => 'process')));
$form->prepare();

....
```

Comment: @FranMercases i changed but  i am still same issues

Comment: Try by changing $this->formText($form->get('name'));  $this->formEmail($form->get('email')); $this->formPassword($form->get('password')); Is really hard to help like this by guessing

Comment: same issues. i know mistake is  there RegisterForm.php  file not other file. still finding what error is there ?

Comment: The error happens at the moment of rendering the view

Comment: Remove filters and validators from RegisterForm.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70911/discussion-between-thennarasu-and-franmercaes).